# How to calculate area of a polygon in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I would like to calculate the area of a portion of the shapefile and computer the percentage ration using ArcGIS 10.2.2

Comment: Hi Piasi and welcome.  This is the kind of task you can probably find in the online documentation.  A quick google search turns up many tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Open the attribute table.  Choose Add Field in the first pull-down menu.  Give it a name and set the type to float or double.  When the new field appears, right-click at the top and choose Calculate Geometry.  Area ought to be a choice in the top box.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answer from J Kelly i would to answer the second part of your question. After you have the Area calculated you create another field with float or double as data-type again.

Then you need the area of your whole set of features. Easiest way for is to right click your area field and choose "statistics". There you have the sum of all your features. For a single calculation it is also easiest to just write down the number(many other ways possible though).

Right-Click your new created field for the percentages and choose "field calculator" and calculate your percantage values by double clicking your area field from the field list and divide it by the number you wrote down. (be careful here if you are used to comma seperation with numbers as ArcGis needs to have a point here for decimal places) Should look similar to:

[Area_Field] / total_area * 100